# Matrix multiplication with complex numbers

Tags: matrices

I am trying to simplify the following inequality 
\begin{align*}
  &\log(1+\mathbf{h}_2^H \mathbf{S}  \mathbf{h}_2) \leq \log(1+\mathbf{h}_1^H \mathbf{S}  \mathbf{h}_1)
\tag1
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{h}_2^* := \begin{bmatrix} x  \\ z \\ \end{bmatrix},
\mathbf{h}_1^* := \begin{bmatrix} y  \\z \\ \end{bmatrix},
\mathbf{S} := 
\begin{bmatrix} 1-|\rho_1|^2 & \rho_3 - \rho_1 \rho_2^* \\
\rho_3^* - \rho_1^*\rho_2 & 1-|\rho_2|^2 \\ \end{bmatrix},
\end{align*}

where $A^H$ means hermitian of matrix $A$ and $A^*$ is conjugate of $A$ and we have
$$|\rho_i| \leq 1, i=1,2,3,$$

When I perform the actual matrix multiplication I get the following
$$|x|^2(1- |\rho_1|^2) + 2 \, \text{Real}\, \{x z^*(\rho_3-\rho_1\rho_2^*)\} \leq |y|^2(1- |\rho_1|^2) + 2 \, \text{Real}\, \{y z^*(\rho_3-\rho_1\rho_2^*)\} \tag 2 $$

If my calculation is correct, can (2) be simplified?

Comment: OK I get it. From the monotonicity of $\log$, (1) is equivalent to $h_2^HSh_2\leq h_1^HSh_1$. The form of the (Hermitian) matrix $S$ is not really important but of course the forms must so that both log arguments are positive.

Comment: Another question: since $h_i$ are supposedly complex, how would you define $x\leq y$?

Comment: that is good question, then maybe $x\leq y$ is wrong and it should be $|x|\leq |y|$.  I am not sure.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel, you mean by your question that $x,y,z$ are in general complex so how can i write $x<y$ right?

Comment: Right. The claim is certainly true if the off-diagonal terms of $S$ are zero (and reduce to $|x|\leq|y|$ in that case) but I don't think this will be true in general (consider first the real case for simplicity).

Comment: I think after we multiply the matrices, we will end up with just the magnitude of x,y,z. Take for example ${\bf h_2^H}=[ 1 -j] $ then $\mathbf{h}_2 :=$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\j \\ \end{bmatrix} so the product  ${\bf h_2^H S h_2} $ has no complex number anymore.

Comment: If $S$ is as is (Hermitian), $h_i^HSh_i$ is always real. But consider, e.g., the real case: $h_1^TSh_1-h_2^TSh_2=(y-x)[s_{11}(x+y)+2s_{12}z]$ with $S=\pmatrix{s_{11}&s_{12}\\s_{12}&s_{22}}$. You can clearly notice the dependence on $z$. The only dependence missing is that on $s_{22}$.

Comment: but I am interested in simplifying this inequality with S as is hermetian.

Comment: Does it change anything? If it is not true for a real symmetric $S$, it won't be true when it is complex Hermitian.

Comment: I see your point, I just want to see whether the above can be simplified into a nice expression. btw I added the result of the actual matrix multiplicaiton to the question. @AlgebraicPavel

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
$$x \le y$$
$$\Rightarrow \ x \cdot y^{-1} \le 1$$
If you translate multiplication and division back to matrix multiplication and inversion, then this second inequality would be true. However, this says nothing about the "hidden" variables within $x$ and $y$...

Here's a more involved one...

$$\log(1+a) \le \log(1+b)$$
Since the left must be less than the right hand side...
$$1+a \le 1+b$$
$$\Rightarrow a \le b$$
Of course, if you limit the domain of the log function you get...
$$-1 \le a \le b$$
and
$$-1 \le b$$

Intuitively this is true. Through a change of variables this can be rigorously proven.

Comment: thanks, but which 1, do you mean the one in the logarithmic term? Why wouldnt it be a scalar, notice that $\bf{h_2^H S h_2}$ is scalar.

Comment: @Tyrone Oops, my mistake. Fixed that.